# Can i use python to start a program in a different terminal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unix

I would like to use python to open a program. This is possible, however the program then occupies the terminal so the loop stops. Can i use python to start the program in a different terminal? This is in a linux system (raspberry pi 4 to be specific)

using:

```py
import os

os.system('npm start')
```

I managed to open the program. I would like to do something similar in a new terminal, so that the loop continues.

Comment: you should abord your problem like this ; which command to start to open a terminal, and launch a command inside this terminal. See 'term' or 'xterm' command, for xterm look at -e option. When you have solve this problem, put command inside os.system (or subprocess.rm() )

Comment: cheers, ill yhave a look